# Hơw to resolve error when query CLOB json in ORACLE 19c

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c

Created Database (in Oracle 19c) and table name is `s_inv` with a Column name is `doc` and type is `CLOB`.

I create "check (doc is JSON)" and run query below the OR condition is wrong. 1=1 but it's resolve ((1=1) or ... or ...) = false

```
Select *
From s_inv a
Where
    a.sec<>'njr9e9ngd9'
    And (
          (1=1)
       Or (a.doc.root.sec='njr9e9ngd9')
       Or (a.doc.root.sec='omr36o6r43')
   ) Order by id
```

Comment: Are you getting an Oracle error code, e.g. ORA-01403? Or does your query not return the expected result?

Comment: It's a successful query but infectedRow is 0. Although i can select 1 record by same 'where' condition